# How do I debug Lumia Imaging output in a Windows Runtime Component project?

Tags: c++-cx, lumia-imaging-sdk

I have a WinRT project and am trying to debug some of my filter chains. Whenever I set a breakpoint and try to inspect a Lumia::Imaging object (e.g., Bitmap^, BitmapImageSource^, BlendEffect^, etc.), this is what I see:

"Information not available, no symbols loaded for Lumia.Imaging.dll"

How do I get VS to load the symbols for Lumia.Imaging.dll? I've tried adding "Lumia.Imaging" to the Symbols options in VS, but no luck.

Comment: Highly doubtful you are using c++/cli if you are doing winrt.  Did you perhaps mean c++/cx?

Comment: If that's the case, then why are extension methods in the System namespace unavailable to me?

Comment: Because C++ doesn't do "extension methods" (we have Koenig lookup which is more powerful)

Comment: Hmm... maybe I am confused on the difference. How can I know for sure whether it's c++/cx or c++/cli?

Comment: Does the code use `gcnew` or `ref new`?

Comment: This is for a "Windows Runtime Component" project in VS.

Comment: That's C++/CX, winrt reference counting.  C++/CLI uses gcnew (.net garbage collector)

Comment: Thanks. I'll correct the question.

Comment: So, if something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598390(v=vs.110).aspx  suggests that the extension is available in C++, that's simply because it's a managed C++ app?

Comment: To C++ it's just a static member function. The call-it-like-an-instance-member syntax is not available. Which the documentation you linked tells you, it says that syntax is available (only) in c# and vb.net

Comment: Sure, but the System namespace isn't even available to me. And I can't find that static method in the Platform namespace either.

Comment: Stuff from .NET framework is available in C++/CLI not C++/CX. I have no idea about bridge stuff that is both .Net and winrt, like that one, because I don't do winrt.